# Ruby on Rails, How to Update Div with Ajax on like/unlike

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, haml

So the problem I am having is getting my like/unlike button to refresh with ajax in my Ruby on Rails app, here is my code:

> app/views/_comment.html.haml

---

```
- likes = comment.likes
%div.comment{id: "comment-#{comment.id}"}
  .comment-avatar
    .medium-user-avatar.avatar-canvas
      - if comment.user.avatar_url
        = image_tag comment.user.avatar_url(:medium)
      - else
        %span.medium-user-initials.initials-decoration
          = comment.user.avatar_initials
  %span.comment-username= link_to(comment.user_name, "#")
  %span.comment-body~ markdown(comment.body)
  .comment-time
    = time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + " ago"
    - if can? :like, comment
      = " · "
      - if likes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
        = link_to "Like", like_comment_path(comment), method: :post, remote: true
      - else
        = link_to "Unlike", unlike_comment_path(comment), method: :post, remote: true
    - if comment.user == current_user
      = " · "
      = link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete, remote: true,
        :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?" }
  - if likes.count > 0
    .comment-likes
      - likers = likes.map { |like| link_to(like.user_name, "#") }
      - if likers.length > 1
        - likers = likers.slice(0, likers.length - 1).join(", ").concat(" and " +     likers.slice(-1))
      - else
        - likers = likers[0]
      = "Liked by #{likers}".html_safe
```

> app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

---

```
class CommentsController < BaseController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def destroy
    destroy!{ discussion_url(resource.discussion ) }
  end

  def like
    comment_vote = resource.like current_user
    Event.comment_liked!(comment_vote)
    #redirect_to discussion_url(resource.discussion )
    render :partial => "like"
    comment_likes
  end

  def unlike
    resource.unlike current_user
    #redirect_to discussion_url(resource.discussion)
    render :partial => "unlike"
    comment_likes
  end

  def comment_likes
    render :partial => "comment_likes"
  end
end
```

and then the .js.erb files for like, unlike and comment_likes:

> app/views/_like.js.erb

---

```
$(".comment-time a#like").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('.comment-time a#like'")
```

> app/views/_unlike.js.erb

---

```
$(".comment-time a#unlike").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('.comment-time a#unlike'")
```

> app/views/_comment_likes.js.erb

---

```
$(".comment-likes a##").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('.comment-likes a##'")
```

Currently clicking like will update the database but will not show the changes until a page refresh, I just want to refresh the individual div's with ajax. A little more information about the div's could help so the ruby creates the html  and contained in that as an example is   or  when already liked I just need to refresh these divs to show the latest from the database aswell as  which contains http://localhost:3000/comments/7/unlike 500 (Internal Server Error)"

The rest of the scripting has been done in coffeescript if that matters? I read that the controller functions should use .js.erb so hope this isn't affecting it all. (Im sure my js.erb's are wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **your Controller does not know how to respond to the ajax request.** By default the render method will *render html.erb* or in your case *html.haml* templates.

Unless you do something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { comment_likes }
end
```

Now if an ajax requests comes in the _comments_likes.js.erb template will be rendered.

If you have more of these ajaxy type questions [there are efforts being put into rewriting the ajax guides for rails.](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7493)

[And by the by, please consider cleaning up your view.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/55-cleaning-up-the-view)

Comment: Thanks for this would love some better guides have searched the web everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the main problem but one thing to fix would be the render statement in your .js.erb files.

The Rails render method requires as its argument the erb template or action to render. When you call:

```
render('.comment-time a#unlike')
```

Rails will try to find a template with the name ".comment-time a#unlike" somewhere in your view path which will probably raise some kind of error. Make sure you pay attention to the difference between what's happening in your javascript (in the client) in your application (on the server.)

So one way to fix this would be as follows. First check what part of the view you want to update, for simplicity's sake because you already have the _comment partial let's use that. Second figure out which part in the dom it should replace, in your case the div with the current comment's ID. We can then do the following:

```
$("#comment-<%= @comment.id %>").replace_html(
  "<%= escape_javascript render('comments/comment', :comment => @comment) %>"
);
```

This will render the `_comment.html.erb` partial in `app/views/comments`, insert the result (escaped) into the javascript in your (dis-)like.js.erb and send that back to the browser to execute. The browser will then `replace_html` on the comment's div (indicated by the ID.)

Because we're replacing the whole comment div you can use the same method for both like and dislike. If you need to save bandwidth you could fine tune it to only re-render the like button itself, but for now this will work.

Comment: Thanks, this helped with part of the problem.